# Combining cube functions with LookupCube

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, olap

Can I combine [cube functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Cube-functions-reference-2378132b-d3f2-4af1-896d-48a9ee840eb2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) with [LookupCube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/lookupcube-mdx) function from MDX, in Excel 2016?

I cannot find any example how to do it.

I would like to merge data from different cubes (using LookupCube) and filter it using CUBEVALUE and CUBEMEMBER functions. Without LookupCube I need to have both filters for two cubes.

Comment: Why not setup multiple connections in Excel rather than having SSAS do the connecting to the other cube for you? I think the answer is no that you can't use it in CUBEVALUE or CUBEMEMBER functions because they take a member reference and LookupCube() returns a number.

Comment: Because I would like to change filters in one place, not separately for all cube connections. I am looking for solution for end users.